# Formatting a string to firstname and last name

Tags: groovy, format

Is there any simple way to format a string 'abc xyz' to 'Abc Xyz' in groovy script? 
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Split and capitalize? Use a library?

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be:

```
def name = 'abc xyz'.split()*.toLowerCase()*.capitalize().join(' ')
```

But you need to think...  What happens to `Mike O'Hara`?

Comment: I cant think of any solution to handle those fancy names :/

Comment: Generally, it comes down to people typing people's names in right...  Though Dave's right...there may be a library for this...

Comment: Also, that's not a "fancy name", it's a regular name that you'll have to consider

Comment: I doubt there is a library for this, that does it right... take for example "Vincent van Gogh". "van" could very well be a middle name instead and  written capitalized. There are countries with multiple such particles used on a regular base too